# Database - logging the changes of entity

Tags: mysql, database, logging, storing-data

The question is about how to do it properly.

Situation:
I have a table with products and I need to log changes to it so that it would be easy to see by who and when some property was changed.

Every product entity contains (just a few properties to name):

- expire_date  - DATETIME format
- series    - VARCHAR(255)
- package   - INT(32 )  (how many items are in package)

In the future I will have more properties to log. (about 10-15)

This is its basic structure for table which will store information about changes.

```
          [
       'id' => 'pk',
       'type' => 'INT(32)',
       'product_id' => 'INT(32)',
       'user_id' => 'INT(32)',
       'data_old' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
       'data_new' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
       'created' => 'DATETIME'
          ], 'ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8');
```

This will work fine for **series** attribute.

But what's about  expire_date and package?
Storing them into VARCHAR would be silly, I guess.

I face the following solutions:

- Storing all attributes in VARCHAR
- Creating field for each type of attribute, so I'll end up with fields as data_old_varchar, data_new_varchar, data_old_int, data_new_int, data_new_datetime, data_old_datetime
- Creating a separate table for each type of attributes , e.g.I would have tables  product_logging_varchar, product_logging_int, product_logging_datetime
- Creating a separate table for logging of each type of attribute, e.g. product_logging_series, product_logging_expire_date, product_logging_.... ( and about  15 tables more ,poll)

I like none of  options above.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

On my experience, I've always implemented tables audit (logging) by creating a copy of each table with a prefix (audit_TableName) and 3 more columns:

1. Username   // Who do action
2. When       // Date of action
3. What       // Insert, Update or Delete

Usually (Oracle, MySql) trigger has been used to fill this table.
So for each table, 1 more table and 3 triggers (insert,update,delete).

Its a bit heavy and painful if database structure change often but this solution always worked for get any data historical/logging/audit, as :

- Get all history of a specific data
- Get update timeline / user activity
- Reload a previous state of data
- Activity happen in interval of time/date
- ...

I heard of a tool who do well the job : https://flywaydb.org/, but never used it yet.